# AddRange in give public access to list

Tags: c#, .net, generics, properties

I have some legacy C# code with the following piece:

```
private List<MyClass> mList = new List<MyClass>();

public List<MyClass> getList()
{
   List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
   list.AddRange(mList);
   return list;
}
```

Not sure what is the purpose of `AddRange` here? Can I rewrite it as:

```
public List<MyClass> getList()
{
   return mList;
}
```

Comment: Yes. From the code shown, that should be enough.

Comment: Not exactly the same since `getList` creates a new list with the same objects whereas `return mList` returns even the same list. So if you would call `getList().Clear()` also the original list would be cleared.

Comment: This property has an ugly side effect, because it implies that you can change the state of the owning class by modifying the returned list. Returning an `IEnumerable` or making it a method would be the appropriate thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

If you simply use `return mlist`, you return the `mlist` instance, whereas the original code returns a shallow copy of it.

---

Say your class looks like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        mList.Add(1);
    }

    private List<int> mList = new List<int>();

    public List<int> getList()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        list.AddRange(mList);
        return list;
    }
}
```

And now you run

```
var x = new Foo();
x.getList().Add(2);
x.getList().Add(3);
```

The content of `mList` will still be a single `1`, because the calls to `getList` returned copies of `mList`, not the list itself.

If you change the code like you did in your question, you would have altered `mList` it would now contain the elements `1`, `2`, and `3`.

---

It's not clear from the method name that a copy is returned, so you maybe want to change it to something like `GetListCopy` (in which case the method could simply return `new List<MyClass>(mList)` or `mList.ToList()`), or return the list as a [`IReadOnlyList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx) to make clear that the list should not be changed.

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<MyClass> getList()
{
    return mList.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Comment: This lacks an explanation

Comment: @TimSchmelter What do you think is not explained? The original code returns a copy of the list, the new code returns the `mList` instance.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to be very familiar with C# and asks a basic question. So answering that it returns a shallow copy instead of the original list might be correct but it is not very helpful if OP doesn't know what it means. When does it matter/makes a difference? (f.e. if you call `Clear()`)

Comment: @sloth: How does it make any difference? because if I change any value in the copied list, it will get changed in the original list well. Please clarify. Any benefits with using copied instance instead of original?

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed if you just use `return mList;` it'll return the original list and not a copy of it.

However you can simplify it by using :

```
public List<MyClass> getList
{
   return mList.ToList();  // returns copy of original list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. 
This might result in some unexpected behaviour in you software because the code as it is creates a new instance of List and your solution has the same instance returned everytime the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

The only purpose here is to clone original list to keep it unchanged.
But, it is better to re-write this property and turn it to the method:

```
public List<MyClass> getList()
{
   // note, that Enumerable.ToList() does the same
   return new List(mList);
}
```

`List<T>` constructor checks for `ICollection<T>` implementation in source `IEnumerable<T>`, and properly sets initial capacity. Since every call will create new instance, this shouldn't be a property, but a method.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's comment and Sloth's already gives correct explanation.

Just an additional point:

```
private List<MyClass> mList = new List<MyClass>();

public List<MyClass> getList1()
{
    List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
    list.AddRange(mList);
    return list;
}

public List<MyClass> getList2()
{
    return mList;
}
```

`getlis1()` -
(1) Keeps the original list *safe*. `Add()` or `AddRange()` or `Clear()` doesn't affect it.
(2) **Throws** exception if `mList` is null!

`getlis2()` -
(1) Exposes the original list `mList`. `Add()` or `AddRange()` or `Clear()` affects (modifies) it.
(2) Returns `null` if `mList` is null!